# How to make a slider with the middle item is bigger than others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

[image: Slider]

I want to realize the same slider as shown at the picture. My middle item is always bigger than the others. I need to use different sizes of images for active slide and the slides that are placed to the sides. So I think to use such as code:

```css
li {
  width: $small-item-width;
  height: $small-item-height;
  &.active {
    width: $big-item-width;
    height: $big-item-height;
  }
  position: relative;
  .item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<div class="big-item"></div>
<div class="small-item"></div>
</li> 
<li class="active">
<div class="item big"></div>
<div class="item small"></div>
</li>   
</ul>
```

The only solution I found at Internet is the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with center mode. But the markup that is used here is not suitable for my case 'caurse there are only one  child to slide.
[image]

```
 <div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

So I want to use any plugin and to add class "active" to li then the slide is active. Can anyone knows how to make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
&.active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```